# Import error: Error importing scipy

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, importerror

import pandas
　　　　Traceback (most recent call last):
  　　　　File "", line 1, in 
　　　　File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 37
, in 
    import pandas.core.config_init
 　　　　 File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py",
 line 18, in 
    　　　　from pandas.formats.format import detect_console_encoding
  　　　　File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", l
ine 16, in 
    　　　　from pandas.io.common import _get_handle, UnicodeWriter, _expand_user
  　　　　File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 5
, in 
  　　　　  import csv
 　　　　 File "csv.py", line 10, in 
   　　　　 field_size_limit, \
 　　　　 File "csv_test.py", line 4, in 
   　　　　 from scipy import stats
 　　　　 File "scipy/**init**.py", line 103, in 
    　　　　raise ImportError(msg)
　　　　ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while
        　　　　being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source
       　　　　 tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter.

I tried to import pandas by invoking python from bash.
Before doing so,I used 'which python' command to make sure which python I'm using.
It interacted to me saying "/Users/...(Usersname)/anaconda/bin/python".
But when I imported pandas from IPython of anaconda's distribution, successfully imported.
for the record,I added csv_test.py module by hand.
guess this module is doing something wrong?
it just imports scipy.stats and matplotlib.pyplot.
So I hope it is not affecting any other module.
seems something seriously wrong is going on here,judging from Error sentence..

Comment: don't know why but <module> is omitted after "File 'x',line ~ ,in"

Answer (score 1):

The csv_test.py file you have "added by hand" tries to import scipy; as the error message says, don't do that.

You can probably place your test code in a private location, without messing with the scipy installation directory.

I suggest uninstalling and reinstalling at least pandas and scipy, possibly everything, to eliminate intentional and unintentional alterations.

Comment: So,is it alright to do 'conda uninstall pandas( and scipy)'? I don't know very well about how to use conda install command..